# Print all rows in GTK Treeview Mono

Tags: c#, windows, monodevelop, xamarin, gtk#

I have a single-cloumn treeview in gtk# and I need to get all values from the rows on my treeview

```
myTreeView.AppendColumn ("Path", new CellRendererText (), "text", 0);
myTreeView.Model = new ListStore (typeof(string));
```

Is there a way to iterate on each row and get the row value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this and it worked ok for me.

```
TreeIter iter;
myTreeView.GetIterFirst(out iter);
for (int i = 0; i < myTreeView.IterNChildren(); i++)
{
    myTreeView.GetValue(iter, ... );
    //Do stuff.  
    myTreeView.IterNext(ref iter);   
}
```

Comment: Really useful - the first example of this which has actually worked for me. Thank you very much. FYI, I had to change mine a bit: `TreeIter iter;
   myTreeView.Model.GetIterFirst (out iter);
   for (int i = 0; i < myTreeView.Model.IterNChildren(); i++)
   {
    myTreeView.Model.GetValue (iter, 0);
    //Do stuff.
    myTreeView.Model.IterNext(ref iter);
   }`

Comment: @BenHayward - Just so you know - this is the question that got me onto SO in a serious way. I looked for the solution, saw the question was unanswered, and when I finally had the solution I thought maybe I'd actually post an answer on SO for once...